# How to maintain a menuBar and StatusBar through all the app in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, statusbar

I cannot find any answer to this after one hour looking for it.

Is there anyway I can keep like a "template" for all my windows in my application so they allways have the same `StatusBar` and `Menu`? So I don't have to add it manually everytime I create a Window, because then, if I add for example a `MenuItem` I need to add it to all the windows. Also, to keep the same Grid Layout, even this is not so important.

Something like when in PHP you use a default template and just change the body of it.

This is my actual code:

```
<Window x:Class="studies.myWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:studies"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="My window Title" Height="720" Width="1280" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundKey}" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            [...]
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            [...]
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <Menu HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0 0 0 20 " Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="12"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="New _Company"/>
                <MenuItem Header="New _Proyect"/>
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="_Exit" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>

        <StatusBar HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="12" Grid.Row="12"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FF212121" BorderBrush="#FF696969" >
            <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>

            <StatusBarItem>
                <TextBlock Name="lblCursorPosition" Text="Conectado como: daniaguado" Foreground="{DynamicResource LightForegroundBrush}" FontSize="10" IsEnabled="False" />
            </StatusBarItem>
            <Separator Grid.Column="1" />
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock  Foreground="{DynamicResource LightForegroundBrush}"/>
            </StatusBarItem>
            <Separator Grid.Column="3" />
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="4">

            </StatusBarItem>

        </StatusBar>

        <!-- Content goes here -->

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: You could make that a `Resource` and just reuse it in your different pages while also adding new content to it

Comment: @MattL. All the examples I find for `Resource` are related to Styles and so on, how can I convert components to a resource?

Comment: You can make anything a resource. In your `App.xaml`, make a resource section: `<Application.Resources></Application.Resources>` and between those tags, copy the control you want to make a resource. All you need to do extra is give it a key, `x:Key="name"`. The key is what you use to find the resource. Here's some more info http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/wpf-application/resources/

Comment: I'll try to find out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that inherits from Window, and add your common stuff to that.

Then, the windows in your application would use MyWindow instead of Window. This allows custom C# as well.

The downside is that you'd probably have to add the common controls in code, rather than using the designer, but it does give you what you want.

Sorry, can't post sample code right now as I'm on a tablet, but if you can't work this out, let me know and I'll try and show some code next time I'm on my PC

Comment: As I'm using XAML for coding the views, wouldn't be writing components in code contradictory?

Comment: Why would it be contradictory? Custom controls are often written in code. You're probably thinking that code should be kept out of views wherever possible, and you're right, but this is slightly different, in that the code here **is** the view.

Comment: Ok. I got the point. Can I include also the Grid in that custom `MyWindow` or should I add that to the XAML always? Because the `StatusBar` and `MenuBar` are accommodated on that `Grid`.

Comment: @Dani If they are part of the base window, then by all means add them to the custom window.

Comment: Yes, those 3 things are the ones I want to keep in all the application. The Grid and both bars.